# Interpolation with httparty request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, interpolation, httparty

I want to make a http request (using httparty gem) to facebook graph to check if a token which comes form the client is valid or not, but I suppose that interpolation doesn't work with httparty

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=#{params[:access_token]}")
render json: response
```

but this gives me the response

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad signature","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose that interpolation doesn't work with httparty

Interpolation is a Ruby syntax feature; your string gets interpolated before it's ever passed to HTTParty.

You could have debugged this by inspecting the URL:

```
uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=#{params[:access_token]}"
Rails.logger.info(uri)
response = HTTParty.get(uri)
```

Regardless, when using query parameters with HTTParty, you shouldn't use interpolation anyway. You should pass them with the `:query` option, which will ensure that the parameters are encoded correctly:

```
response = HTTParty.get( "https://graph.facebook.com/me",
                         query: { access_token: params[:access_token] })
```

However, I'm not certain this will actually fix your problem. There's a good chance the problem is really somewhere else in your OAuth flow--there's a lot of room for error when working with OAuth.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, but tnx for the answer. The only solution I found is to use Net::Http